# Car with wheel colliders jumps when collides with another box collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, wheelcollider

So, I make a car using wheel colliders. Also I have a simple scene with a box collider. The problem is that when wheel colliders touch box collider, the car takes off in the sky and starts turning. What I'm doing wrong?[This is how wheel colliders are tuned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFRO1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this was a very stupid mistake. I just turned off is Trigger for box collider of the scene, and all started to work well. I hope it will help someone)